# Laravel mailtrap not working on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, mailtrap

I have a Laravel 7.0 project, when I try to send email to mailtrap it gives me following error.

> Swift_TransportException Unsupported sendmail command flags []. Must
>   be one of "-bs" or "-t" but can include additional flags.

I have following in my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=MY_USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Also tried to clear config cache, but it does not work.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: The command for clearing the cache is `php artisan cache:clear` .
Or if you want to clear only configuration cache - `php artisan config:clear` .

Comment: what does your `config/mail.php` file look like?

Comment: what's the line in your code where you're sending the mail? i think this might not have anything to do with mail trap

Comment: @ahappydev i have tried all of these cache clear things, but getting same issue.

Comment: @maximus1127
this is the code i have inside my controller
Mail::to("example@email.com")->send(new TestEmail($data));

For this i have created a mailable through 
php artisan make:mail TestEmail

and by the way i have imported namespaces as well inside controller
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\TestEmail;

Comment: What does `dd(config('mail'));` show (blank out any secret values)?

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to restart your queue and run work again:

`php artisan queue:restart`

`php artisan queue:work`

[From the docs:](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment)
Since queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not notice changes to your code without being restarted. So, the simplest way to deploy an application using queue workers is to restart the workers during your deployment process.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, try this if you are using gmail, also add **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=********@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=*********gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Solved the issue.